# django override module class

Tags: python, django

I am using a module, from which I need to extend a class.

```
#name.module.py
""" Lots of code """
class TheClassIWantToExtend(object):
   """Class implementation

"""More code"""
```

so in my django root, I now have

```
#myCustomModule.py
class MySubclass(TheClassIWantToExtend):
  """Implementation"""
```

How can I make sure that MySubclass is used instead of the module's original class?

EDIT: I should maybe add that the original module has been installed with pip install module and that it's in a virtualenv

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Why not? You can extend the core django modules and classes by using them as a base.

Comment: @jrd1: Except that you can't reliably force existing code to use your class instead.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Ah! Good point. Duly noted. Thanks!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams you're so right and it's actually obvious. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply **tell Django to use your class instead, in any method or class that requires a particular instance of the parent class that you wish to extend.**

Example:

If this is your project:

```
$ python django-admin.py startproject testdjango

testdjango
├── testdjango
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

And you create your application (which comes with its own models):

```
$ python manage.py startapp utils

testdjango
├── testdjango
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
│
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── views.py
    └── urls.py
```

Let's say that we want to extend `UserCreationForm`, to do so you'd do the following in your `utils/models.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Since you wish to extend the `UserCreationForm` class, your class
# has to inherit from it:
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    # your implemenation specific code goes here
    pass
```

Then, to use this extended class, you'd use it where you'd normally use the parent class:

```
# UserCreationForm is used in views, so let's say we're in the view 
# of an application `myapp`:
from utils import MyUserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render

# And, here you'll use it as you had done with the other in some view:
def myview(request, template_name="accounts/login.html"):
    # Perform the view logic and set variables here
    return render(request, template_name, locals())
```

While this is a trivial example, a couple of things to remember: always register your apps in the project settings, and when improving upon your extension, you should always examine the source code of the class you're trying to extend (as found in `site-packages/django`), otherwise things'll will go south very quickly when things don't work they usually do.

Comment: While the question is _old_ I must say that this does not answer the original question. Assuming the module is `pip install`, there is no realistic way to "tell django to use your class instead, in any method or class that require a particular instance of the parent class that you wish to extend" if the module utilizes its own class throughout.

Comment: @Felipe: Thank you for your comment. At the time the OP posted their initial question, I believed this was an appropriate response. In light of their updated entry and in review of the comment history, it isn't. I kept it up since in case it could be beneficial to others.